# How To Run Docker Container Bash Commands From NodeJS Code

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, command-line-interface, influxdb

I need to get the size of an InfluxDb on disc. I am able to get the size on the windows cmd(I am in windows 11) using **du -sh /var/lib/influxdb2/**.

The problem is now that i want to access this data using node.js. Using child process, i can run docker commands and get the ouput e.g. **docker ps**.

But when i run docker exec -it influxdb du -sh /var/lib/influx2/engine which is the bash command, i am getting "**the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'**"

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `exec` instead of `exec -it`

Answer (score 0):

docker exec -it nameofcontainer -- /bin/bash helps us to login to the container and after that you would be able to use du -sh /var/lib/influx2/engine to check the disk space

Comment: Still getting the same error as mentioned above

Comment: seems problem  creating  interactive terminal while using -it flag . can you try this winpty docker exec -it nameofcontainer bash and later du -sh /var/lib/influx2/engine